# How to display cell value offset active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to display the value of a cell according to my ActiveCell or Target Cell using a Function. The cell I'm trying to display is in the same spreadsheet.

My objective is to create a Header in the spreadsheet that would display information according to the position of the Active cell.

I've tried this code and typed the function `=VendorName5()` in the cell where I want the value to be displayed but it seems to be missing something. Can you help ?

---

```
Function VendorName5() As String

Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4)

       VendorName5 = Name

End Function
```

---

OK, found it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 8 Then
        Range("C2") = Cells(Target.Row, 2)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code in the Worksheet code module? Also, I'm assuming this is `VBA`, not `VB.net`.

Comment: Yes it's in the module. yes it's VBA

Comment: I don't think you can use ActiveCell during a UDF as part of a worksheet function.  What's your end goal here? If you just want to know the value of a cell 4 columns to the left then you could, for example, put `=A1` in cell E1

Comment: This works for me if i put the code in an ordinary code module, but does not work if I put it in the worksheet code module.  Excel 2010.

Comment: Also if you **really** indeed it to be a dynamic function baseon the `ActiveCell` this should be fine using the `Worksheet_Change ()` event.

Comment: I really need to create a dynamic function based on ActiveCell. I've never used Worksheet_Change() yet can you give some tips ?

Answer (score 2):

This is VBA not VB.NET

Try `.Value` of Cell

```
Function VendorName5() As String

    Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value

    VendorName5 = Name

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `Offset` function:

In cell A1:

`=OFFSET(A1,0,4,1,1)`

Or, refer to the cell directly:

`=E1`

etc.

This seems overkill to use a UDF to do something that worksheet functions ordinarily allow for, already.